# covariance matrix is not positive definite

Tags: covariance

I have a feature vector(FV1) of size 1*n. Now I subtract mean of all feature vectors from the feature vector FV1 Now I take transpose of that(FV1_Transpose) which is n*1. Now I add do matrix multiplication (FV1_Transpose * FV1) to get covariance matrix which is n*n.

But my problem is that I dont get a positive definite matrix. I read everywhere that covariance matrix should be symmetric positive definite.

FV1 after subtraction of mean = -17.7926788,0.814089298,33.8878059,-17.8336430,22.4685001;

Covariance matrix = 
316.579407, -14.4848289, -602.954834, 317.308289, -399.774811
-14.4848289, 0.662741363, 27.5876999, -14.5181780, 18.2913647
-602.954834, 27.5876999, 1148.38342, -604.343018, 761.408142
317.308289, -14.5181780, -604.343018, 318.038818, -400.695221
-399.774811, 18.2913647, 761.408142, -400.695221, 504.833496

This covariance matrix is not positive definite. Any ideawhy is it so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the matrix is not positive definite? I did the following in octave.

```
A = [ 316.579407, -14.4848289, -602.954834, 317.308289, -399.774811 -14.4848289, 0.662741363, 27.5876999, -14.5181780, 18.2913647 -602.954834, 27.5876999, 1148.38342, -604.343018, 761.408142 317.308289, -14.5181780, -604.343018, 318.038818, -400.695221 -399.774811, 18.2913647, 761.408142, -400.695221, 504.833496]
A = reshape(A, 5, 5)
svd(A)
```

The eigen values of A as obtained from svd were.

```
2.2885e+03
5.4922e-05
1.5958e-05
1.3636e-05
1.1507e-08
```

Please note that all the eigen values are positive.
Now, A is symmetric (being a co-variance matrix), To verify,

```
A - A'
```

would give you a 5 x 5 zero matrix

A symmetric matrix which has positive eigen values should be positive definite.

[reference](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~clark/285/2006-07/handouts/pos-def.pdf)